# Как загружать первый fragment в Activity при запуске приложения?

Tags: java, android

При запуске приложения запускается пустая Activity, как запустить первый Fragment из бокового меню?

Код Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Fragment_Go fgo;
    Fragment_Programs fprograms;
    Fragment_Settings fsettings;
    Fragment_Statistic fstatistic;
    Fragment_Uprajnenia fuprajnenia;
    Fragment_zameri fzameri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        fgo = new Fragment_Go();
        fprograms = new Fragment_Programs();
        fsettings = new Fragment_Settings();
        fstatistic = new Fragment_Statistic();
        fuprajnenia = new Fragment_Uprajnenia();
        fzameri = new Fragment_zameri();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


        if (id == R.id.nav_go) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fgo);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_programs) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fprograms);

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_uprajnenia) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fuprajnenia);


        }else if (id == R.id.nav_statistic) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fstatistic);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_zameri) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fzameri);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, fsettings);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        ftrans.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Код Fragment_Go:

```
public class Fragment_Go extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Fragment_Go() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment_Go.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment_Go newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment_Go fragment = new Fragment_Go();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__go, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Разметка контейнера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.sharkitt.sportplus.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/container">



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: возможно для первого фрагмента нужно использовать ftrans.add(), а не ftrans.replace()

Comment: Нет, ничего не изменится

Comment: тогда выложите R.id.container

Comment: в `onCreate()` активити пропишите запуск нужного фрагмента "напрямую", а не через нажатие кнопки меню

Comment: pavlofff, если так сделать, потом при нажатии меню на другие фрагменты, первая не будет накладываться на остальные? И вообще можно будет ее запустить из меню потом?

Comment: да, конечно можно. накладываться не будет, если замещать фрагменты методом `replace()`, а не `add()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет! Сам недавно столкнулся с этой проблемой, и нашел для себя такое решение:
В onCreate в конце вставь это:

```
 //Start fragment
    Fragment fragment = new твой_фрагмент();
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: примерно так и сделал, спасибо! В инете находил много подобных тем и все они без ответов.